# Swipe Refresh Layout animation is stuttering

Tags: android, asynchronous, rx-java

I am developing an Android application where I need to check a web service for updates everytime the user wishes to. This involves quite a bit in the background, and I used SwipeRefreshLayout to indicate the updating act.

I assumed the refreshing animation happened async, and independent of any work im doing to fetch the updates, but when I perform a pull, there are visibles stutters in the animation thoughout the process, ruining the whole process visually. Any ideas on why this is happening and thoughts on how to fix it? I havent included code in case that the info i have provided is enough, if not, i will supply the necessary code sample.

The code looks something like the following:

```
onRefresh()
{
    startService(syncServiceIntent);
}
```

The service then checks the service and updates a local database with any possible updates using an API call that returns an Observable of my data. After finishing, I broadcast it and upon receiving this broadcast, I accordingly repopulate my RecyclerView using another Observable of my data, and finally on

```
onCompleted()
{
    //do some stuff
    mSwipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);
    //do some other stuff
}
```

Why is the animation stuttering?

Comment: Are you running, God forbid, the check on the main thread? Or through, for example, an AsyncTask?

Comment: No, I am using a service in which I use RxJava to perform the updates, but aside from that, why is the refresh animation affected by the work I'm doing in the update process?

Comment: Since the code is working, this may be better suited for [codereview.stackexchange.com](http://codereview.stackexchange.com).

Comment: @miken32 code that isn't working ***as intended*** is off-topic on CR. "any ideas on why this is happening and thoughs on how to fix it" is definitely not working as intended. Please see [a guide to CR for SO users](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/q/5777/23788) on CR.Meta.

Comment: @Mat'sMug fair enough; I figured if it's working but just not as efficiently as desired, that CR was the place for it. Will keep those guidelines in mind in the future.